# How to run polyml on mac via Terminal?

Tags: sml, polyml

So i have installed the latest version of polyml on my mac . How can I run the compiler to start using it?? 
for sml it is farily simple, i just type 'sml' and it starts working?

Comment: `brew install polyml`

Comment: This is how to install it....

Comment: I figured it out !!   simply type 'poly' on Terminal window and voilla !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
rlwrap poly
```

will make your life easier